# Block explorers for a private testnet

Tags: private, testnet

Are there block explorers available that can be run locally and set up to observe a private network of Tezos nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are various open-source projects that you can use for this:

Some examples:

- [TzStats](https://github.com/blockwatch-cc/tzstats)
- [TzKt](https://github.com/baking-bad/tzkt)
- [TezBlock](https://github.com/airgap-it/tezblock)